# App crashes at launch "Appname keeps stopping". ClassNotFoundException and InflateException

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMdr2.png)I`m new in programming and i checked every q\a i could, but didnt find a working solution for my issue :(

Whenever i start an app, it immediately crashes with a message "Appname keeps stopping". I got ClassNotFoundException and InflateException, all dependencies in gradle are installed correctly, the path to the file is correct as well (at least i think so). It is an educational project, part of it was predownloaded. There is single activity with a single fragment in it, which should be active upon app launch.

Screenshots with current path:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMdr2.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz4sO.png)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.unscramble, PID: 7717
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.unscramble/com.example.android.unscramble.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.GameFragment: make sure class name exists
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadFragmentClass(FragmentFactory.java:97)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:611)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:483)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.java:171)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:52)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:302)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:273)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:115)
        at com.example.android.unscramble.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.GameFragment
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadClass(FragmentFactory.java:53)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadFragmentClass(FragmentFactory.java:94)
            ... 34 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.GameFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.unscramble-SMPtJZpeKsSBNf3fCMLZeg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.unscramble-SMPtJZpeKsSBNf3fCMLZeg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 38 more
```

The only line, that seems weird to me is this one. However, i dont know what to do with it.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.GameFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.unscramble-SMPtJZpeKsSBNf3fCMLZeg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.unscramble-SMPtJZpeKsSBNf3fCMLZeg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

Here are code snippets:

GameFragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import com.example.android.unscramble.R
import com.example.android.unscramble.databinding.GameFragmentBinding
import com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.MAX_NO_OF_WORDS
import com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.allWordsList
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder

class GameFragment : Fragment(R.layout.game_fragment) {
    
    private val viewModel: GameViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout XML file and return a binding object instance
        binding = GameFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        Log.d("GameFragment", "GameFragment created/re-created!")
        Log.d("GameFragment", "Word: ${viewModel.currentScrambledWord} " +
                "Score: ${viewModel.score} WordCount: ${viewModel.currentWordCount}")
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

       
        binding.submit.setOnClickListener { onSubmitWord() }
        binding.skip.setOnClickListener { onSkipWord() }
      
        updateNextWordOnScreen()
        binding.score.text = getString(R.string.score, 0)
        binding.wordCount.text = getString(
            R.string.word_count, 0, MAX_NO_OF_WORDS)
    }
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.android.unscramble

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.main_activity) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/game_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.GameFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

game_fragment.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
        tools:context=".ui.game.GameFragment">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/skip"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:text="@string/skip"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/submit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/submit"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/skip"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textField" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_instructions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/instructions"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textField"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_unscrambled_word" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_unscrambled_word"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView_instructions"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/word_count"
            tools:text="Scramble word" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/word_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/word_count"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView_unscrambled_word"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="3 of 10 words" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/score"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Score: 20" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textField"
            style="@style/Widget.Unscramble.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:hint="@string/enter_your_word"
            app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_error"
            app:helperTextTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/submit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_instructions">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/text_input_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textPersonName|textNoSuggestions"
                android:maxLines="1" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.GameFragment` is the correct fully-qualified class name for this fragment? My guess is that `GameFragment` resides in some other package -- if it were in `com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game`, then you would not need the `import` statements for `MAX_NO_OF_WORDS` and `allWordsList`.

Comment: @CommonsWare i think so, I attached two screenshots (links) to the post

Comment: What does the `package` line at the top of `GameFragment` have in it?

Comment: @CommonsWare i guess it is predownloaded first part of the project. However, at the beginning i extracted the project, only after that i imported it.

Comment: @CommonsWare i think it has something to do with ListofWords, other files do not allow to use it`s variables without direct import requests for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that the `package` line at the top of your `GameFragment` file does not match the directory in which you have the file. Kotlin allows you to do that, though you should be getting a warning about it in the IDE. So, while the file is positioned in the correct place, the `package` line says what package Kotlin will use for the class. If the `package` line has something else — or is missing entirely — that would explain your error.

Ideally, Kotlin source follows the Java rule: the `package` and the directory are in alignment, using the same segments in each. In your case, that would mean that the `package` line at the top of `GameFragment.kt` should be:

```kotlin
package com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to inflate Game Fragment dynamically by doing this:

in main_activity.xml place:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Instead of

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/game_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.unscramble.ui.game.GameFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Then in Main Activity's onCreate call this:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, GameFragment()).commit()
```